# newbie question: connect two functions int two files

Tags: javascript, function

This is a newbie question. I have two javascript and one html files. When I click on an image it goes to the first .js file and when it finnish to run all that code should go to the second .js file. But how can I connect the two functions that are in different files.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes to the first .js file" and "should go to the second .js file"? Do you want to call the two functions with the same image passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what files the functions are in, you can call the second function from the first one.

You should also consider why you are separateing your functions into seperate files - in general, they should all be in as few files as possible.

Comment: I like your name :p I guess you're producing Heisenbug's like a lot.

Comment: I have in separeted files to organize all the project. The code from the second function is quite big. But I can call the second function in the same way I call the first one?

Comment: Yes you can - There are reasons for separating into multiple files, so it may be OK, but I was worried that you might think you had to do it, as you admitted to being a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

you need just to define the 2 js files in the HTML header page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="one.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

In file1.js:

```
var foo = function(){
    bar();
};
```

In file2.js:

```
var bar = function(){
    alert('hello');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have something like this,

in the html file:

```
<input type="button" name="" onclick="random1();" />
```

in the first js file:

```
function random1(){
// your code here
random2();
}
```

in the second js file:

```
function random2(){
//your code here
}
```